# How to exclude transitive dependencies with scope provided with maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, transitive-dependency

I need to create a jar-with-dependencies. I'm using maven assemply plugin 3.1.0.

I want to:

- include dependencies with scope `compile` and that, transitively
- exclude dependencies with scope `provided`.

IE, in the following case as shown by `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:provided
```

I want to include in the final jar `json-path`, `json-smart`, `accessors-smart` but NOT `slf4j-api`.

With the default `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor, I also have `slf4j-api` included in the resulting jar.

1/ Is it the intended behavior? This seem in contradiction with other maven resolution.

2/ what is assembly descriptor that allows to get what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of maven-assembly-plugin do you use?

Comment: oups sorry - version 3.1.0, added in the main description too.

Comment: Based on the predefined descriptor there should be no jar which is scope provided being packaged. Are you sure that is does not exist in other areas...Can you show the full pom file?

Comment: I did a minimal reproduction project here: https://github.com/fanf/test-maven-assembly

Comment: maven-shade-pluing seems to do what is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it seems to just not work with the assembly plugin, and until explained why it is otherwise, I believe it's a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-883

I created a minimal project to demonstrate the problem here:  https://github.com/fanf/test-maven-assembly

The solution is to use the shade plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) which is correctly excluding transitive dependencies with scope `provided` (and can do many more things than the `assembly` plugin regarding uber-jar).

Comment: did you succeed to use the shade plugin and obtain a jar with jars inside and not classes?

Comment: @Caroh I didn't try, I don't know if it's possible, sorry